Spectrum of $\prod_i^d \left(I-x_ix_i^T\right)$ for isotropic $x_i$
Suppose $x_i\in \mathbb{R}^d$ are IID isotropic random vectors with $\|x_i\|=1$ and  matrix $A_d$ is defined as follows:
$$A_d=\prod_i^d \left(I-x_ix_i^T\right)$$
Is anything known about the spectrum of $A_d$ for large $d$, like the limiting spectral density? In particular, I'm interested in singular value density around $1$ which appears to be same as singular value density of $X$ around 0 where $X$ is an IID Gaussian matrix, why?
This operator represents $d$ steps of LMS filter on random normalized data.


$k$th moment $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)\approx d \left(1 - \frac{1}{d}\right)^d \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$
Notebook

related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/316603/11260

@CarloBeenakker thanks, that's indeed related (Kaczmarz). A heuristic argument gives $\operatorname{Tr}(A)$ since multiplying by random projection matrix reduces the expected trace by a factor of $(1-1/d)$ ...curious why $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)$ decays as $O(1/\sqrt{k})$

for the record: the $k$-th moment is more accurately given (for large $d$) by $\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)\approx d \left(1 - \frac{1}{d}\right)^{kd} \frac{k^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$.

I'm following up on your recent question: As found there, the $k$-th moment of the singular values squared $\sigma^2$ (eigenvalues of $A_dA_d^\top$) is given for large $d$ by
$$\mathbb{E}[\sigma^{2k}]=\frac{k^k}{k! e^k}.$$
This does not correspond exactly to a known probability density function, but it is closely matched by $\sigma^2=e^{-\pi y}$ with $y\sim\chi^2_1$ distributed according to the chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom. The moments are then given by $(1+2\pi k)^{-1/2}$, which has the right large-$k$ asymptotics and agrees already well for small $k$.
Here I show a test for $d=1000$, blue is the set of $\sigma^2_i$ obtained from the product of random projections, red is generated by the $\chi_1^2$ distribution.

To gain some more insight into this distribution, I allow for a variation in the number $n$ of the projections, considering the singular values of
$$A_n=\prod_i^n \left(I-x_ix_i^\top\right),\;\;x_i\in \mathbb{R}^d.$$
I take the double limit $d\rightarrow\infty$, $n\rightarrow\infty$, at fixed ratio $\rho=n/d$. Setting up the recursion relations for the moments of the singular values, as described here, I find that
$$\mathbb{E}[\sigma^{2k}]=\frac{G(k,\rho)}{e^{k\rho}(k-1)!}$$
is given by the Erlang delay function.$^\ast$
Now I can consider the large-$k$ asymptotics, and I find
$$\mathbb{E}[\sigma^{2k}]\sim\begin{cases}
1-\rho&\text{if}\;\;0<\rho<1,\\
k^{-1/2}&\text{if}\;\;\rho=1,\\
k^{-3/2}e^{-(\rho-1-\ln\rho)k}&\text{if}\;\;\rho>1.
\end{cases}$$
This asymptotics can be interpreted in terms of the von-Neumann-Halperin theorem of alternating projections: For large $k$ the product $A_n^k$ converges to the projector onto the intersection of the subspaces of the $n=\rho d$ individual projections in $A_n$. If $\rho<1$ this subspace can be expected to have rank $d-n=d(1-\rho)$, so a fraction $1-\rho$ of the singular values of $A_n^k$ is equal to 1 and the rest equals 0. The moments then become $k$-independent, equal to $1-\rho$. If $\rho>1$ the intersection of the subspaces can be expected to be empty, with exponentially small singular values of $A_n^k$ as result. The case $\rho=1$ from the OP is the threshold between an empty and non-empty subspace intersection, with a power law decay.

$^\ast$ A few cases: $\{\mathbb{E}[\sigma^{2k}]|k=1,2,3,4\}=\left\{e^{-\rho},e^{-2 \rho} (\rho+1),\tfrac{1}{2} e^{-3 \rho} \left(3 \rho^2+4 \rho+2\right),\tfrac{1}{3} e^{-4 \rho} \left(8 \rho^3+12 \rho^2+9 \rho+3\right)\right\}.$
I have no idea why the Erlang function from queing theory pops up here, and welcome any insight.

